# How to pass default values to a Jenkins build using the Parameterized Build Plugin?

Tags: parameters, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using the [Parameterized Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) in Jenkins. I want to provide a link to the build page, but configure the default value for one of the fields that shows up in the form. This value is going to be different every time the job is run, but I want it to be configurable from some other page. Essentially I want to do something like click on a link that looks something like this:

```
https://jenkins/job/Sandbox/build?delay=0sec&Test=foo
```

And see this on the build screen:

[image: Jenkins build with default parameter Test=foo]

So then I can fill out the rest of the values (or even modify the default value) and then click Build. Is this possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely doable - there is a plugin for that:

[Build With Parameters Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+With+Parameters+Plugin).

Just install it and change the url to actually use the plugin:

```
https://jenkins/job/Sandbox/parambuild?Test=foo
```

And that's should do it...

Comment: Builds, Parameterized Builds, Builds With Parameters, Jenkins has it all. Thanks - that plugin does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 20):

You **don't need** any additional plugins for this. This comes natively with Jenkins

`https://jenkins/job/Sandbox/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&Test=foo`
The above will trigger the build job immediately (or whatever the delay may be). This is suitable for automation.

The [Build With Parameters Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+With+Parameters+Plugin) is similar, but it will open a Jenkins confirmation page with pre-populated parameters (from the URL), and prompt the user to click the <kbd>Build</kbd> button. It is not suitable to automation.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the fact that you can pass parameters without any additional plugins. It's not exactly what I needed for this use case, but this is the correct approach when you *want* to skip the build screen.

Comment: In installation I use it says "You must use POST method to trigger builds. (From scripts you may instead pass a per-project authentication token, or authenticate with your API token.) If you see this page, it may be because a plugin offered a GET link; file a bug report for that plugin." but there is "Proceed" button, and after clicking it it works.

Comment: How can we avoid clicking Proceed button? Every time I have to click it manually and it is not anymore automated.

Comment: @limonik use `/buildWithParameters?token=mytoken&Test=foo`. The "token" needs to be set on per-project configuration under "Build Triggers > Trigger builds remotely" section

Answer (score 0):

You can work with build triggers `/build?token=TOKEN_NAME or /buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN_NAME&Test=foo&AnotherTest=(your value)`

Comment: Hello All, I am looking for Build triggers with delay option and will send some parameters like above /build?delay=0sec?token=TOKEN_NAME&Test=foo, but it is not working.. please suggest any