# Is there a way to pre-populate Jenkins build page for parameterized builds?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that takes environment name as a parameter. On another site/dashboard, I would like to create links to this Jenkins job. But the link should pre-populate the parameter based on where it was clicked from.

Something like this,

```
<a href="https://jenkins/<someJenkinsAPI>?ENV=env1">env1</a>
<a href="https://jenkins/<someJenkinsAPI>?ENV=env2">env2</a>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you not have the option to select a parameter of type "Choice"? The first value in the predefined  list is the "default" if the build is just run. There are several "Extended Chicory plugins which give you greater flexibilty. Search plugins.Jenkins.up for choice or parameters

Comment: @IanW Yes, I'm already using the choice parameter. I just wanted a specific choice pre-selected from the dropdown upon visiting a certain URL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass default values to a Jenkins build using the Parameterized Build Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024936/how-to-pass-default-values-to-a-jenkins-build-using-the-parameterized-build-plug)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just came across this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-with-parameters
With this, you just need to go to a URL like this: `https://jenkins.mycompany.com/job/nikhil-test/parambuild/?ENV=env2&APP=myapp`

This will open up the `/buildWithParameters` page for that job, with the values from your URL pre-populated on the page! If you don't provide a parameter OR provide an invalid value for the parameter, it will pre-populate that parameter with the default value.

[image: build page]

Comment: Thank you for this. But, say I have a buildA which pushes a version of a library to some artifactory, say I create a new buildB, how do I create a choice(or a dropdown) in buildB to prepopulate all the versions including the latest one for the library to be used in buildB?

Comment: Do you know if this plugin works with CascadeChoiceParameter PT_CHECKBOX (aka multiple choices)?